# How to check if responseBody does not contain string in postman tests

Tags: postman

To check for a string in the responseBody, we do the search as follows

```
tests["Body matches string"] = responseBody.has("string_you_want_to_search");
```

How to check if responseBody does not contain string in postman tests ?

Answer (score 34):

The most "natural" and readable syntax is as follow, using a "fluent" style API

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () 
{
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.not.include("string_you_want_to_search");
});
```

As Stefan Iancu pointed out, this only seems to work in the standalone version of Postman.

Comment: Note that you need the standalone version of Postman, not the Desktop app, for this to work.

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
tests["Body does not have supplied string"] = !(responseBody.has("string_you_want_to_search"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Body does not contain string_you_want_to_search"] = data.search("string_you_want_to_search") < 0;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.